# CiviMail Social Media Media Integration

Tags: civimail, social-media

I'd like to know if there is anything newer than [this August, 2013 post](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=29069.msg127172#msg127172) regarding how to include social media "share this email" links in CiviMail.

Thanks.

Comment: No reply. :) I'm curious as well. One of my clients wants to add a button (just like with Events where you can share you Event on FB) in his newsletter so that readers can share that Newsletter on FB. Haven't found out if it is available. In the meantime I will try to use the solution as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'll bite, I've got a client with the same request and I'll bet lots of people would use it if it was there.

The post you reference has some code for how to create a token that can be used in manually building some html to include in your email, which in theory is all your really need.

What would be nice is:
1. A series of tokens for each of the different social media share options to simplify the civimail editor's job.
2. A test by those tokens that would hide the share links on emails that aren't configured for public archiving.

Sounds like a simple extension. Or what was your experience?

As an aside, here's what a CiviCRM competitor is offering: https://blog.aweber.com/email-marketing/social-share-buttons-in-your-emails.htm